# Join Query which should return one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query which will retrieve me the fullname (available in fullname) of the ownerid and creatorid. Since both are referring the same table, it is retrieving me two rwo. But I need fullname for both ownerid and creatorid fullname in one row. How to do this? owner id and creator id is the reference name in userdetail table.

create table page(page_key,page_number,ownerid,creatorid)

create table userdetail(id,fullname,phonenumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join table `userdetail` twice since you want to get the `fullname` of two ids in you table `page`

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.fullName as OwnerName,
        c.Fullname as CreatorName
FROM    page a
        INNER JOIN userdetail b
            ON a.ownerid = b.id
        INNER JOIN userdetail c
            ON a.creatorID = c.id
```

One more thing, if `ownerid` and `creatorID` can be null, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Please don't ***teach*** people to use `AS a`, `AS b` and `AS c` as aliases :( Why not use `userdetail AS Owner` and `userdetail AS Creator`?

Comment: uhm, because i used to do it. and I don't know why. :D i've been already doing it for 7 years @Dems . :(